# HTML Designer Interface

Tags: c#, html, .net, frameworks

I have searched a couple of hours, but did not found a fitting solution. Here is my Problem:

My Software (C#, WPF) contains the functionality to send automatically mails to customers. Therefore, I like to offer an interface to create an html mail template (Header/Footer) to give the mails an professional look.
A Freeware/Framework like the 'Ask Question' Interface in Stack Overflow would be awesome.

Greetings Leo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look [here](http://smithhtmleditor.codeplex.com/), you could reuse this to build up your email template, and save it.

You could then allow the user to set special tags in it such as `{{name}}` or `{{orderDescription}}`, that you then parse to fill the html string output before sending.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That is what i was searching for !